# Bash - How to replace line that includes '/' characters

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to replace a line in a csv file that includes '/' characters in one of its columns. Is there a way to replace it with sed? I'm using two variables: one to store the line to replace and another one for the string that will replace it.

```
sed -i "/s/${CURRENTLINE}/${NEWLINE}/g"
```

example of the line format:

907;name;2015;4444;DOC;44;user;06/03/2015

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Your sed command starts with `s` and you can use an alternate reges delimiter:

```
sed -i "s~${CURRENTLINE}~${NEWLINE}~g" file.csv
```

Comment: You clearly know this is a duplicate, why have you answered it ?

Comment: @JID: I usually check question listed in **Related** section for any dups but on this one I didn't find anything exact dup.